# How does EclipseLink/MOXy create the property name?

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I am writing a code to set `XmlTransient` at runtime using MOXy. Here is the part of the code which is adapted from the example on http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-refresh-example.html

```
public void setXmlTransient(Class<?> domainClass, String propertyName) {
    XmlTransient xmlTransient = new XmlTransient();
    xmlTransient.setJavaAttribute(propertyName);
    JavaType javaType = getJavaType(domainClass);
    javaType.getJavaAttributes().getJavaAttribute().add(objectFactory.createXmlTransient(xmlTransient));
}
```

Since I am doing this programmatically, I need to be able to create the `propertyName` exactly the same way as MOXy does. For most getter method names, like `getOrder`, the property name is done by removing `get` from the method name and change upper-case `O` to lower-case `o`, i.e. property name is `order`. However, I am hitting the case which my getter method is `getXInA` but `xInA` doesn't seem to be a valid property name. MOXy throws a warning like

```
Ignoring attribute [xInA] on class [Atom] as no Property was generated for it.
```

Does anyone know what the rules are used by MOXy for creating the property name from getters? or know where I can find out about this without reading the MOXy source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

Because there are two capital letters in a row the property name is going to be `XInA`.

---

**LONG ANSWER**

***Domain Model (Foo)***

Below is a sample Java class with the property from your question.

```
package forum14945664;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String x;

    public String getXInA() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setXInA(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

***MetadataSource (ExampleMetadataSource)***

`MetadataSource` is a programmatic way to provide MOXy with the mapping metadata.

```
package forum14945664;

import java.util.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.metadata.MetadataSourceAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.JavaType.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.XmlBindings.*;

public class ExampleMetadataSource extends MetadataSourceAdapter {

    private ObjectFactory objectFactory;
    private Map<Class<?>, JavaType> javaTypes;
    private XmlBindings xmlBindings;

    public ExampleMetadataSource() {
        objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        javaTypes = new HashMap<Class<?>, JavaType>();

        xmlBindings = new XmlBindings();
        xmlBindings.setPackageName("forum14945664");
        xmlBindings.setJavaTypes(new JavaTypes());
    }

    @Override
    public XmlBindings getXmlBindings(Map<String, ?> properties, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        return xmlBindings;
    }

    public JavaType getJavaType(Class<?> clazz) {
        JavaType javaType = javaTypes.get(clazz);
        if(null == javaType) {
            javaType = new JavaType();
            javaType.setName(clazz.getSimpleName());
            javaType.setJavaAttributes(new JavaAttributes());
            xmlBindings.getJavaTypes().getJavaType().add(javaType);
            javaTypes.put(clazz, javaType);
        }
        return javaType;
    }

    public void setXmlTransient(Class<?> domainClass, String propertyName) {
        XmlTransient xmlTransient = new XmlTransient();
        xmlTransient.setJavaAttribute(propertyName);
        JavaType javaType = getJavaType(domainClass);
        javaType.getJavaAttributes().getJavaAttribute().add(objectFactory.createXmlTransient(xmlTransient));
    }

}
```

***Specify MOXy as JAXB Provider (jaxb.properties)***

To specify MOXy as the JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***Demo***

In the demo code below we will create a `JAXBContext` based on the domain model and we will marshal an instance to XML.  Then we will use the `MetadataSource` to make the property transient, refresh the `JAXBContext` and marshal the instance again.

```
package forum14945664;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExampleMetadataSource metadata = new ExampleMetadataSource();

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, metadata);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setXInA("Hello World");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

        metadata.setXmlTransient(Foo.class, "XInA");
        JAXBHelper.getJAXBContext(jc).refreshMetadata();
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

First we see the `XInA` property marshalled, then after we make it transient we see that it is not in the XML from the second marshal operation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <XInA>Hello World</XInA>
</foo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. This solved my problem. All I can do is to give you a vote up but that's still not enough.

Comment: @gigadot - I have entered the following enhancement request to make the message we log in MOXy more useful:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/401510